# 20 Sec Delay when sending email through mail() Apache+PHP5.3+sendmail?

Tags: php, apache, email, centos, sendmail

Today I discovered that my website contact form takes about 20 seconds to send an email in my Godaddy Centos VPS server.

I investigated this problem and found that the source is caused by PHP `mail()` function.  When I type a message on my website's contact page and click on send button, it takes about 20 seconds before page load completes.

Create a test.php file with the following PHP code to test the mail:

```
<?php

mail("myemail@mydomain.com", "Test", "Test");

?>
```

I ran the command: `php test.php` on server.

I inspected the `/var/log/maillog` and it appeared that the email had been sent instantly without any delay.

The 20 seconds delay only happened when I executed my code through my website.  I assume that this has something to do with Apache user, because the command line with user root can send the email without delay.

Here's the mail log when I send the email through the console with user root:

```
Apr 10 14:57:04 ip-103-1-173-250 sendmail[27681]: r3ALv4i3027681: from=root, size=174, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201304102157.r3ALv4i3027681@ip-103-1-173-250.ip.secureserver.net>, relay=root@localhost
Apr 10 14:57:05 ip-103-1-173-250 sendmail[27681]: r3ALv4i3027681: to=john23157@gmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30174, relay=myserver, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Accepted message qp 20459 bytes 684)
```

I replaced the `relay=` value with `myserver` in this post for security reasons.

From the above maillog, it is clear that the email was send instantly, and I did receive the email.

Here's the mail log when I send through my website contact form:

```
Apr 10 14:54:22 myhostname sendmail[27655]: r3ALsMjV027655: from=support@mydomain.com, size=940, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<d946feca6d6640910e2db02d541aa704@mydomain.com>, relay=apache@localhost

Apr 10 14:57:56 myhostname sendmail[27655]: r3ALsMjV027655: to=john23157@gmail.com, ctladdr=support@mydomain.com (48/48), delay=00:03:34, xdelay=00:03:34, mailer=relay, pri=30940, relay=myserver, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Accepted message qp 21186 bytes 1297)
```

The above maillog shows the delay of 3 minutes and a half.

I have no idea what is causing the delay when send through Apache.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: mostly such delays are caused by network issues

Comment: Could you send a test message in verbose mode as user apache? `(echo subject: test; echo to: xxx@gmail.com; echo from: support@mydomain.com ; echo ; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t -v -fsupport@mydomain.com` It may help to narrow down possibilities by locating delayed delivery stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hek2mgl says, unfortunately most such things are caused by network issues–one of the mail servers that is in the chain may be overwhelmed or some part of the network might just be slow at that point. When I was developing my own PHP application, I experienced similar issues.

Since you have your own VPS, I would recommend installing your own SMTP server. I used [PostFix](http://www.postfix.org/), but there are others. You then configure it so that it replaces the built in unix `sendmail` command. You can find [instructions on how to install postfix at the CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix)

If this is set up correctly, calling `mail()` from PHP will add the message to the send queue in Postfix, rather than trying to contact an external mail server. It will return immediately (meaning your app will feel much faster), while Postfix will keep trying to send the email in the background for as long as it needs to.

Comment: -1: if user2205533 doesn't already have a MTA installed then mail() would return immediately (with an error).

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I now installed the PostFix just to send the mail out but not receive as I have a mail Server which is not on the same server as my website.  Now the email is now send straight away.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on experts exchange and it fixed this exact issue for me.

--- Pasted Below ---

My problem was that Sendmail looks for a fully qualified domain (FQDN) name, which I did not have in my hosts file.  Once I changed it from this:

127.0.0.1      localhost

127.0.1.1      webserver

to this:

127.0.0.1      localhost localhost.localdomain webserver

Answer (score -1):

I'll bet you a weeks salary it's not caused by PHP's mail() function.

The mail() function is a simple wrapper around an exec call which invokes the CLI interface to the MTA. Simply exec'ing a program is unlikely to have such a delay - every time I've come across this problem it's a result of the MTA trying to offload the message synchronously and running into problems along the way (badly configured DNS, missing smart hosts, ident lookups....).

Since it's a VPS you have control over how the MTA is (mis)configured. And that's a topic for ServerFault - not Stackoverflow.

(BTW did you check the configs were the same for the CLI and webserver SAPI? Did you try to exec the CLI *from* the webserver sapi?)